# I want to make my array global in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

How can I make my `infoArray` global so that I can access it from anywhere just by importing it and the data also remain in it, while information is given to it on different pages?

Can you tell me how to declare it in this file?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
export default function Menu(props) {
  
  const infoarray = [] ; 
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="location sample">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot favicon"></i>
        We operate in NOIDA and DELHI only.
        {/* window.open("/insert/your/path/here"); */}
      </div>
        <div className="go" >
          <Link to="/cart"> 
            <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"/>
              </Link>
            <div className="text">
              Go to cart
            </div>
        </div>

      <hr className="line" />
      {/* <hr className="line" /> */}
      <div className="about-us">
        You can share your designs on WhatsApp
        <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>
        <a href="https://wa.me/<>" target='_blank' rel="noreferrer" className='no'>9650988301</a>
        we can make the same on the cake.
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

// export  infoArray ;
```

Comment: Move it to outside the function before exporting it?  What you're asking doesn't appear to be related to React in any way, or have anything to do with the contents of that `Menu` component.  You're just asking about variable scope in JavaScript.  To export `infoArray` from the module, it has to exist at the module level.  Just like `Menu` exists at the module level and is exportable.  (Though, as an aside, it's *highly likely* that what you're trying to do isn't a good idea in the first place...)

Comment: Will that remain same ?

Comment: Use context API or Store eg. Zustand

Comment: @Ankit will the values inside the array change over time? Or will it always hold the same values?

Comment: @David sir can you show in this Menu.jsx becaue I though exactly the same and tried but I am getting some error.

Comment: @Alex sir once  something is pushed in the array that particular will not change bur data will indeed be added

Comment: @Ankit: [Like this?](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-feather-7gx5bp?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks, sir I was just declaring the array inside the Menu. I have one more question, will the array hold the information as I move to different files, where more strings will be pushed.

Comment: @Ankit: Test it and find out.  Generally in a React application one would maintain data in state, not in global or module variables.  But we don't know what functionality you're trying to achieve or why you're not using state, there could certainly be a valid reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

In this file you can define the array before exporting the default function like this:

```
const infoarray = []; 
export default function Menu(props) {}
```

Or

You can declare a global context variable in any of the parent components and this variable will be accessible across the component tree by `this.context.varname`.
Just specify `childContextTypes` and `getChildContext` in the parent component and after that you can use/modify this from any component by just specifying `contextTypes` in the child component.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use **Store**, for example `Zustand`:

1. install zustand
2. Create Store

   ```
   import create from 'zustand'

   const useArray = create((set) => ({
     arrayVal: 0,
     setArray: () => set((state, value) => ({ array: value }))
   }))
   ```
3. To use it, in any component

   ```
   const arrayVal = useArray((state) => state.arrayVal)
   ```
4. and there you have it.

---

Another Option is to use **localStorage**

1. To set the value

   ```
   localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(val));
   ```
2. To get the value

   ```
   JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
   ```